# Register multiple users from single device on ejabberd server?

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I am working on `smack chat library` on `ejabberd` server. After  ejabberd configuration, i am able to register users from multiple devices at the same time also login multiple users and users are able to chat correctly but problem is that, when i am registering multiple users from same mobile device quickly. it is getting error like:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLErrorException: SASLError using DIGEST-MD5: not-authorized
```

and  in `ejabberd.log` file i found:

```
<error code='500' type='wait'><resource-constraint xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Users are not allowed to register accounts so quickly</text></error>
```

But when i am going to register users from same device after some time it is working fine.
I search on internet alot but i could not find appropriate solution so please give me appropriate solution and is there any way to reduce the time of the user registration from single device. My ejabberd.yml file:

```
 ###
###'           ejabberd configuration file
###
###

### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained in more detail
### in the ejabberd Installation and Operation Guide.
### Please consult the Guide in case of doubts, it is included with
### your copy of ejabberd, and is also available online at
### http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/docs/

### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
### However, ejabberd treats different literals as different types:
###
### - unquoted or single-quoted strings. They are called "atoms".
###   Example: dog, 'Jupiter', '3.14159', YELLOW
###
### - numeric literals. Example: 3, -45.0, .0
###
### - quoted or folded strings.
###   Examples of quoted string: "Lizzard", "orange".
###   Example of folded string:
###   > Art thou not Romeo,
###     and a Montague?

###.  =======
###'  LOGGING

##
## loglevel: Verbosity of log files generated by ejabberd.
## 0: No ejabberd log at all (not recommended)
## 1: Critical
## 2: Error
## 3: Warning
## 4: Info
## 5: Debug
##
loglevel: 5

##
## rotation: Describe how to rotate logs. Either size and/or date can trigger
## log rotation. Setting count to N keeps N rotated logs. Setting count to 0
## does not disable rotation, it instead rotates the file and keeps no previous
## versions around. Setting size to X rotate log when it reaches X bytes.
## To disable rotation set the size to 0 and the date to ""
## Date syntax is taken from the syntax newsyslog uses in newsyslog.conf.
## Some examples:
##  $D0     rotate every night at midnight
##  $D23    rotate every day at 23:00 hr
##  $W0D23  rotate every week on Sunday at 23:00 hr
##  $W5D16  rotate every week on Friday at 16:00 hr
##  $M1D0   rotate on the first day of every month at midnight
##  $M5D6   rotate on every 5th day of the month at 6:00 hr
##
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1

##
## overload protection: If you want to limit the number of messages per second
## allowed from error_logger, which is a good idea if you want to avoid a flood
## of messages when system is overloaded, you can set a limit.
## 100 is ejabberd's default.
log_rate_limit: 100

##
## watchdog_admins: Only useful for developers: if an ejabberd process
## consumes a lot of memory, send live notifications to these XMPP
## accounts.
##
## watchdog_admins:
##   - "admin@TT_CPU_076"

###.  ===============
###'  NODE PARAMETERS

##
## net_ticktime: Specifies net_kernel tick time in seconds. This options must have
## identical value on all nodes, and in most cases shouldn't be changed at all from
## default value.
##
## net_ticktime: 60

###.  ================
###'  SERVED HOSTNAMES

##
## hosts: Domains served by ejabberd.
## You can define one or several, for example:
## hosts:
##   - "example.net"
##   - "example.com"
##   - "example.org"
##
hosts:
  - "TT_CPU_076"

##
## route_subdomains: Delegate subdomains to other XMPP servers.
## For example, if this ejabberd serves example.org and you want
## to allow communication with an XMPP server called im.example.org.
##
## route_subdomains: s2s

###.  ===============
###'  LISTENING PORTS

##
## listen: The ports ejabberd will listen on, which service each is handled
## by and what options to start it with.
##
listen:
  - 
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    certfile: "C:\\Users\\dharmendras\\AppData\\Roaming\\ejabberd\\conf\\server.pem"
    starttls: true
    ## To enforce TLS encryption for client connections,
    ## use this instead of the "starttls" option:
    ## starttls_required: true
    ##
    ## Custom OpenSSL options
    ##
    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv3"
    ##   - "no_tlsv1"
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
  - 
    port: 5269
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 131072
    shaper: s2s_shaper
  ##
  ## ejabberd_service: Interact with external components (transports, ...)
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 8888
  ##   module: ejabberd_service
  ##   access: all
  ##   shaper_rule: fast
  ##   ip: "127.0.0.1"
  ##   hosts:
  ##     "icq.example.org":
  ##       password: "secret"
  ##     "sms.example.org":
  ##       password: "secret"

  ##
  ## ejabberd_stun: Handles STUN Binding requests
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 3478
  ##   transport: udp
  ##   module: ejabberd_stun

  ##
  ## To handle XML-RPC requests that provide admin credentials:
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 4560
  ##   module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
  ##   maxsessions: 10
  ##   timeout: 5000
  ##   access_commands:
  ##     admin:
  ##       commands: all
  ##       options: []
  - 
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
    ##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    ## register: true
    captcha: false

###.  ==================
###'  S2S GLOBAL OPTIONS

##
## s2s_use_starttls: Enable STARTTLS + Dialback for S2S connections.
## Allowed values are: false optional required required_trusted
## You must specify a certificate file.
##
## s2s_use_starttls: optional

##
## s2s_certfile: Specify a certificate file.
##
## s2s_certfile: "C:\\Users\\dharmendras\\AppData\\Roaming\\ejabberd\\conf\\server.pem"

## Custom OpenSSL options
##
## s2s_protocol_options:
##   - "no_sslv3"
##   - "no_tlsv1"

##
## domain_certfile: Specify a different certificate for each served hostname.
##
## host_config:
##   "example.org":
##     domain_certfile: "C:\\Users\\dharmendras\\AppData\\Roaming\\ejabberd\\conf\\example_org.pem"
##   "example.com":
##     domain_certfile: "C:\\Users\\dharmendras\\AppData\\Roaming\\ejabberd\\conf\\example_com.pem"

##
## S2S whitelist or blacklist
##
## Default s2s policy for undefined hosts.
##
## s2s_access: s2s

##
## Outgoing S2S options
##
## Preferred address families (which to try first) and connect timeout
## in milliseconds.
##
## outgoing_s2s_families:
##   - ipv4
##   - ipv6
## outgoing_s2s_timeout: 10000

###.  ==============
###'  AUTHENTICATION

##
## auth_method: Method used to authenticate the users.
## The default method is the internal.
## If you want to use a different method,
## comment this line and enable the correct ones.
##
auth_method: internal

##
## Store the plain passwords or hashed for SCRAM:
## auth_password_format: plain
## auth_password_format: scram
##
## Define the FQDN if ejabberd doesn't detect it:
## fqdn: "server3.example.com"

##
## Authentication using external script
## Make sure the script is executable by ejabberd.
##
## auth_method: external
## extauth_program: "/path/to/authentication/script"

##
## Authentication using SQL
## Remember to setup a database in the next section.
##
## auth_method: sql

##
## Authentication using PAM
##
## auth_method: pam
## pam_service: "pamservicename"

##
## Authentication using LDAP
##
## auth_method: ldap
##
## List of LDAP servers:
## ldap_servers:
##   - "localhost"
##
## Encryption of connection to LDAP servers:
## ldap_encrypt: none
## ldap_encrypt: tls
##
## Port to connect to on LDAP servers:
## ldap_port: 389
## ldap_port: 636
##
## LDAP manager:
## ldap_rootdn: "dc=example,dc=com"
##
## Password of LDAP manager:
## ldap_password: "******"
##
## Search base of LDAP directory:
## ldap_base: "dc=example,dc=com"
##
## LDAP attribute that holds user ID:
## ldap_uids:
##   - "mail": "%u@mail.example.org"
##
## LDAP filter:
## ldap_filter: "(objectClass=shadowAccount)"

##
Anonymous login support:
   auth_method: anonymous
   anonymous_protocol: sasl_anon
   allow_multiple_connections: true 
##
## host_config:
##   "public.example.org":
##     auth_method: anonymous
##     allow_multiple_connections: false
##     anonymous_protocol: sasl_anon
##
## To use both anonymous and internal authentication:
##
## host_config:
##   "public.example.org":
##     auth_method:
##       - internal
##       - anonymous

###.  ==============
###'  DATABASE SETUP

## ejabberd by default uses the internal Mnesia database,
## so you do not necessarily need this section.
## This section provides configuration examples in case
## you want to use other database backends.
## Please consult the ejabberd Guide for details on database creation.

##
## MySQL server:
##
## sql_type: mysql
## sql_server: "server"
## sql_database: "database"
## sql_username: "username"
## sql_password: "password"
##
## If you want to specify the port:
## sql_port: 1234

##
## PostgreSQL server:
##
## sql_type: pgsql
## sql_server: "server"
## sql_database: "database"
## sql_username: "username"
## sql_password: "password"
##
## If you want to specify the port:
## sql_port: 1234
##
## If you use PostgreSQL, have a large database, and need a
## faster but inexact replacement for "select count(*) from users"
##
## pgsql_users_number_estimate: true
##
## SQLite:
##
## sql_type: sqlite
## sql_database: "C:\\Program Files\\ejabberd-16.09\\database\\ejabberd.db"

##
## ODBC compatible or MSSQL server:
##
## sql_type: odbc
## sql_server: "DSN=ejabberd;UID=ejabberd;PWD=ejabberd"

##
## Number of connections to open to the database for each virtual host
##
## sql_pool_size: 10

##
## Interval to make a dummy SQL request to keep the connections to the
## database alive. Specify in seconds: for example 28800 means 8 hours
##
## sql_keepalive_interval: undefined

###.  ===============
###'  TRAFFIC SHAPERS

shaper:
  ##
  ## The "normal" shaper limits traffic speed to 1000 B/s
  ##
  normal: 1000

  ##
  ## The "fast" shaper limits traffic speed to 50000 B/s
  ##
  fast: 50000

##
## This option specifies the maximum number of elements in the queue
## of the FSM. Refer to the documentation for details.
##
max_fsm_queue: 1000

###.   ====================
###'   ACCESS CONTROL LISTS
acl:
  ##
  ## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
  ## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
  ##
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@TT_CPU_076"

  ##
  ## Blocked users
  ##
  ## blocked:
  ##   user:
  ##     - "baduser@example.org"
  ##     - "test"

  ## Local users: don't modify this.
  ##
  local:
    user_regexp: ""

  ##
  ## More examples of ACLs
  ##
  ## jabberorg:
  ##   server:
  ##     - "jabber.org"
  ## aleksey:
  ##   user:
  ##     - "aleksey@jabber.ru"
  ## test:
  ##   user_regexp: "^test"
  ##   user_glob: "test*"

  ##
  ## Loopback network
  ##
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"

  ##
  ## Bad XMPP servers
  ##
  ## bad_servers:
  ##   server:
  ##     - "xmpp.zombie.org"
  ##     - "xmpp.spam.com"

##
## Define specific ACLs in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     acl:
##       admin:
##         user:
##           - "bob-local@localhost"
###.  ============
###'  SHAPER RULES

shaper_rules:
  ## Maximum number of simultaneous sessions allowed for a single user:
  max_user_sessions: infinity
  ## Maximum number of offline messages that users can have:
  max_user_offline_messages:
    - 5000: admin
    - 10000
  ## For C2S connections, all users except admins use the "normal" shaper
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - normal
  ## All S2S connections use the "fast" shaper
  s2s_shaper: fast

###.  ============
###'  ACCESS RULES
access_rules:
  ## This rule allows access only for local users:
  local:
    - allow: local
  ## Only non-blocked users can use c2s connections:
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  ## Only admins can send announcement messages:
  announce:
    - allow: admin
  ## Only admins can use the configuration interface:
  configure:
    - allow: admin
  ## Only accounts of the local ejabberd server can create rooms:
  muc_create:
    - allow: local
  ## Only accounts on the local ejabberd server can create Pubsub nodes:
  pubsub_createnode:
    - allow: local
  ## In-band registration allows registration of any possible username.
  ## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
  register:
    - allow
  register_from:
    - allow
  registration_timeout:
    - infinity

  mod_register:
    access_from:
      register_from
    access: 
      register
  ## Only allow to register from localhost
  trusted_network:
    - allow
  ## Do not establish S2S connections with bad servers
  ## s2s:
  ##   - deny:
  ##     - ip: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32"
  ##   - deny:
  ##     - ip: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32"
  ##   - allow

## By default the frequency of account registrations from the same IP
## is limited to 1 account every 10 minutes. To disable, specify: infinity
## registration_timeout: 600

##
## Define specific Access Rules in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     access:
##       c2s:
##         - allow: admin
##         - deny
##       register:
##         - deny

###.  ================
###'  DEFAULT LANGUAGE

##
## language: Default language used for server messages.
##
language: "en"

##
## Set a different default language in a virtual host.
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     language: "ru"

###.  =======
###'  CAPTCHA

##
## Full path to a script that generates the image.
##
## captcha_cmd: "C:\\Program Files\\ejabberd-16.09\\lib\\ejabberd-16.09\\priv\\bin\\captcha.sh"

##
## Host for the URL and port where ejabberd listens for CAPTCHA requests.
##
## captcha_host: "TT_CPU_076:5280"

##
## Limit CAPTCHA calls per minute for JID/IP to avoid DoS.
##
## captcha_limit: 5

###.  =======
###'  MODULES

##
## Modules enabled in all ejabberd virtual hosts.
##
modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce
  mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {} # requires mod_adhoc
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_echo: {}
  mod_http_bind: {}
  ## mod_http_fileserver:
  ##   docroot: "/var/www"
  ##   accesslog: "C:\\Program Files\\ejabberd-16.09\\logs\\access.log"
  ## mod_irc: {}
  mod_last: {}
  mod_muc:
    ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_apns:
    address: "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com"
    port: 2195
    certfile: "C:/Users/dharmendras/AppData/Roaming/ejabberd/conf/cert.pem"
    keyfile: "C:/Users/dharmendras/AppData/Roaming/ejabberd/conf/key.pem"
    password: ""
  ## mod_muc_log: {}
  ## mod_multicast: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  ## mod_pres_counter:
  ##   count: 5
  ##   interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  ## mod_proxy65: {}
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    ## reduces resource comsumption, but XEP incompliant
    ignore_pep_from_offline: true
    ## XEP compliant, but increases resource comsumption
    ## ignore_pep_from_offline: false
    last_item_cache: false
    plugins:
      - "flat"
      - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
  mod_register:
    access_from: register_from
    access: register
    ##
    ## Protect In-Band account registrations with CAPTCHA.
    ##
    ##   captcha_protected: true
    ##
    ## Set the minimum informational entropy for passwords.
    ##
    ##   password_strength: 32
    ##
    ## After successful registration, the user receives
    ## a message with this subject and body.
    ##
    welcome_message:
      subject: "Welcome!"
      body: |-
        Hi.
        Welcome to this XMPP server.
    ##
    ## When a user registers, send a notification to
    ## these XMPP accounts.
    ##
    ##   registration_watchers:
    ##     - "admin1@example.org"
    ##
    ## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
    ##
    ip_access: trusted_network
    ##
    ## Local c2s or remote s2s users cannot register accounts
    ##
    ##   access_from: deny
    access: register
  mod_roster: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  ## mod_stats: {}
  ## mod_time: {}
  mod_vcard:
    search: false
  mod_version: {}

##
## Enable modules with custom options in a specific virtual host
##
## host_config:
##   "localhost":
##     modules:
##       mod_echo:
##         host: "mirror.localhost"

##
## Enable modules management via ejabberdctl for installation and
## uninstallation of public/private contributed modules
## (enabled by default)
##

allow_contrib_modules: true

###.
###'
### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8 foldmarker=###',###. foldmethod=marker:
```

Comment: The timeout value looks like a server configuration, so you should probably change it on the server.

Comment: I have done like   registration_timeout: infinity in access rule section in ejabberd.yml file but still same result

Comment: Have you checked this: https://siddharth-ravichandran.com/2010/07/16/ejabberd-resource-constraint-users-are-not-allowed-to-register-accounts-so-fast/

Comment: @Farhan i checked it, it is only telling about to register multiple users from multiple devices not from same device. if there is any way to reduce the time to register users from same device so please tell me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look for `registration_timeout` tag in your `ejabberd.yml` file & set the value to **infinity**.

Ex:

```
## By default the frequency of account registrations from the same IP
## is limited to 1 account every 10 minutes. To disable, specify: infinity

registration_timeout: infinity
```

You should be able to register more than one user from the same device. Though it is suggested to disable **In-band registration** for security reason.

Comment: i have done both of the thing as u told. I am able to register more than one user from same device after take some time but problem is that i am not able to register quickly and i am able to register more than one user from other device so quickly.

Comment: @singh.indolia Can u share your ejabberd config file? + Did u restart the server after making the change?

Comment: Looks like registration_timeout is not being set properly. Please change registration_timeout: -infinity to registration_timeout: infinity

Comment: registration_timeout:  
    - infinity   and registration_timeout: infinity both are same thing in .yml file and same result reflecting on server access rules. i have checked from both but same result.

Comment: if these are not same, i could not register multiple users from different devices quickly.